# Java convert ArrayList<String[]> to String[][]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Do I have to loop through each element to convert `ArrayList<String[]>` to `String[][]` or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just get the contents as an array

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
...
String[][] array = list.toArray(new String[0][0]); // the size here is not important, the array is just an indication of the type to use
```

Comment: It's better to specify the correct size as in `list.toArray(new String[list.size()][])`, otherwise a new array is instantiated with reflection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String[]> l = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    String[] a = {"lala", "lolo"};
    String[] b = {"lili", "lulu"};
    l.add(a);
    l.add(b);

    String[][] r = new String[l.size()][];
    r = l.toArray(r);

    for(String[] s : r){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[lala, lolo]
[lili, lulu]
```